# I/flutter ( 8545): type 'int' is not a subtype of type Iterable

Tags: json, flutter, flutter-web

Class details

```
class AccountInfo
{
  final int total;
  final int loan;

  AccountInfo( this.total,this.loan);
}
```

My function is

```
Future<List<AccountInfo>> _getUsers() async {

    var url = "http://abcwebtest.com/book/accounts.php";
    var para = {'mid': "1"};

    var response = await http.post(url, body: json.encode(para));
    if(response.statusCode ==200) {
      var jsonData = json.decode(response.body);
      List<AccountInfo> accinfo_list = [];

      for (var u in jsonData) {
        AccountInfo usr_acc = AccountInfo( u["total"], u["loan"]);
        accinfo_list.add(usr_acc);

      }

  
      return  accinfo_list;
    }else{
      throw Exception('Failed to load ..........');
    }
  }
```

which will fetch loan and total from table balance. both the fields are int. but I am getting an error as

**I/flutter ( 8545): type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable'**
Please let me help to find solution.

Comment: Which field are you getting error?

Comment: field/column of table total and loan

Comment: can you explain me which field you want to post?

Comment: Just I am sending memberid(column mid) as value=1 to fetch the data total deposit( column total) & loan amount (column loan) from my table named accounts. MY PHP CODE WHERE  mid is received:  
 include('dbc.php');
 $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
 $obj = json_decode($json,true);
 
 $userid=0;
 $userid = $obj['mid'];

Comment: Add ur returned json to the question

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to iterate the stuff that comes back from the server. It's not an array:

```
for (var u in jsonData) {
  AccountInfo usr_acc = AccountInfo( u["total"], u["loan"]);
  accinfo_list.add(usr_acc);
}
```

Instead, do this:

```
Map<string, dynamic> res = json.decode(response.body);
AccountInfo usr_acc = AccountInfo( res["total"], u["loan"]);
accinfo_list.add(usr_acc);
```

Comment: I m getting error : type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' at Map<string, dynamic> res = json.decode(response.body);

Comment: Doesn't seem possible but can the server be sending back a single int as the response.body? You should debug.print(response.body) or set a breakpoint to see what is in there. It's probably not what we are thinking it is.